# Is it possible for two drupal views to share the same pager limit

Tags: views

I have two separate views 'now' and 'next', they both collectively must only have three items. Is there a way for them to share the same pager limit for example if the 'now' view has one item the 'next' view can only display two items as the pager limit is three.

Comment: How do you display them? Page and block? Attachments? Two blocks?..

Comment: They are displayed in two separate blocks

Comment: So the answer is probably *no* - there is no logical connection between them. Of course there usually is a way to hack around limits like this, but it may be a bit complicated to implement it.

Comment: I posted this question on stack-overflow and got a response saying it could be done by 'Then you can alter the second view and put limit and offset by checking the url and getting the page number of the 'now' view.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do that /

Comment: A bit - but with blocks it's tricky to know which one will be actually rendered first. So it's a nice bit of coding and quite a lot of testing and I will not do that for you. See [`views_get_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view/7) - good entry point for interacting with views programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create the blocks yourself, eg, not just via the Block UI and Views, you can hack it together with using various hooks available within Views.

First out the door, I could see using Views' standard block for the `now` View, but in the `next` block,  using `views_get_view_result()` to look at the results of the `now` View and depending upon its result, eg, how many results there are, changing the pager of the `next` View to be whatever you want, in this case 1 or 2.

Note that this of course entails running the `now` View queries twice, so you could create custom blocks containing both Views and statically save the information to be shared across the Page but that introduces other ugliness.

And then if any of these Views are cached, another set of issues crops up.

So, as @molot has mentioned in comments, there is a bunch to think about here.